# jQuery, button message doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*How do I get the text beside my button to change?* Everything else works fine except for these button messages. Thanks for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var fontSizes = [14, 16]
$(function(){
  $('#PlusMinus').click(function() {
      if($(this).val() == "+") {
      $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[1] + 'pt');
      $(this).val("-");
      }else {
        $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[0]+ 'pt');
        $(this).val("+");
      }
   });
});       
<!--NOT WORKING-->
    $("button").click(function () {
    $("h6").toggle();
    });
</script>
</head>
<!--NOT WORKING-->
    <h6>
      <input type='button' value='+' id='PlusMinus'/>
        Larger Text</h6>
    <h6 style="display: none">Smaller Text</h6>
<!--TEXT RESIZES-->
<p id="OurText">My Text!!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

BUTTON STATE 'Message should toggle between *Larger Text* and *Smaller text*'

```
[+] Larger Text

[-] Smaller Text
```

Comment: I have had something similar happen a few days ago. I just went around it with .show() and .hide() and an extra var. This was ugly, but worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "><html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fontSizes = [14, 16]
$(function(){
$('#PlusMinus').click(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "+") {
        $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[1] + 'pt');
        $(this).val("-");
    }else {
        $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[0]+ 'pt');
        $(this).val("+");
    }
    $("body h6").toggle();
});
});
</script>
</head>
<input type='button' value='+' id='PlusMinus'/>
<h6>Larger Text</h6>
<h6 style="display: none">Smaller Text</h6>
<!--TEXT RESIZES-->
<p id="OurText">My Text!!!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The changes I made were:

changed $("h6").toggle(); to $("body h6").toggle(); and moved it up to the $('#PlusMinus').click function

moved the button out of the "Larger Text" h6 element

added < html > tag at the top

removed "Not Working" comments ;)

Comment: @simon see my answer...short & better

Comment: @diEcho yes, that is better - but when you're frantically trying to fix the code you often miss stuff like that...

Comment: @FXquincy No problem! BTW, if you need to put the button and the labels in a div you'll have to change the $("body h6").toggle(); line to $("#myDivId h6").toggle(); for it to toggle the labels.

Comment: Hi! Why is that changing a button text doesn't work in Opera 11.11? (I didn't try it in earlier versions yet.) I tried it with jQuery and with "pure" JavaScript too, none of them worked. This is the jQuery code I tried: $('#blahblah_button').val('Blah-blah'); and this is the "pure" JS-code: document.getElementById('blahblah_button').value = 'Blah-blah';
Why is that none of them worked in Opera 11.11? It does work in IE, Chrome and FF, it surprises me that it doesn't work in Opera. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I rather posted a question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084766/changing-button-text-with-javascript-doesnt-work-in-opera-11-11-for-input-typ

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$(this).val("-");
```

use

```
$(this).attr('value','+');
```

Answer (score 1):

try

first correct the html

```
<input type='button' value='+' id='PlusMinus'/>
    <h6>Larger Text</h6>
    <h6 style="display:none" >Smaller Text</h6>
```

then jquery

```
 $("input[type=button]").click(function () {
    if($(this).val() == '-')
       $(this).val("+");
    else $(this).val("-");
    $("h6").toggle();
    });
```

});

see **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wCASE/)**

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you have:

```
$("button").click(function (){});
```

...but your HTML shows:

```
<input type="button" id="PlusMinus" />
```

You don't want to select a `button` element. You want an `input` element of type button. Try this:

```
$(':button').click( function(){} );
```

...assuming you're not going to select the button by its ID. Note that this could select more than one element, so the ID approach (or some other means of uniquely identifying the button you have in mind) would be preferable:

```
$('#PlusMinus').click( function(){} );
```