# jQuery, call class before addClass and removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code works well, but I have no control of my layout. It toggles between two button states correctly once the link is pressed. **How do I call the 'plus class' before the link is pressed? Please help.** Also, I've tried divs and spans to organize it, but it needs some tweeking
Thanks,

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    #h6{font-size: 12px; padding-right: 0px;}
    .plus{left:0px;height:33px;width:32px; background:url('sprite.gif') 0 0px;}
    .minus{left:0px;height:33px;width:32px; background:url('sprite.gif') 0 -34px;}
</style>
<h6 id="deToggle"><a href="#" class="styles2" id="h6">Larger</a></h6>
<script language="javascript">
    var click = 0%2;
    var fontSizes = [14, 16]
    $('#deToggle').toggle(
        function(){
            var sprot = $('#deToggle');//
            var tog = $('#deToggle');
            tog.html('<a href="#">Larger</a>');
            $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[1] + 'px');
            $(this).val("-");
            tog.addClass('plus');
            tog.removeClass('minus');
        },
        function(){
            var tog = $('#deToggle');
            tog.html('<a href="#">Smaller</a>');
            $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[0]+ 'px');
            $(this).val("+");
            tog.removeClass('plus');
            tog.addClass('minus');
        });
</script>
<p id="OurText">My Text!!!</p>
</html>
```

sprit.gif rollover image
[image]

Comment: I initially thought #h6 is a mistake in your css but then understood you had anchor tag with id 'h6'. that created a great confusion. try to give id's with more meaningful names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to apply the class on the initial page load?

Call the code to add the `plus` class on the initial page load. I've also refactored your code into functions and put it all in jQuery's `document.ready` function

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     Plus();

     $('#deToggle').toggle(function(){
        Plus();
     }, function(){
        Minus();
     });

});

function Plus(){
    var sprot = $('#deToggle');//
    var tog = $('#deToggle');
    tog.html('<a href="#">Larger</a>');
    $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[1] + 'px');
    $(this).val("-");
    tog.addClass('plus');
    tog.removeClass('minus');
}

function Minus(){
    var tog = $('#deToggle');
    tog.html('<a href="#">Smaller</a>');
    $('#OurText').css('fontSize', fontSizes[0]+ 'px');
    $(this).val("+");
    tog.removeClass('plus');
    tog.addClass('minus');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I reply 2 days before something like this

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216063/jquery-button-message-doesnt-change/5216146#5216146)

ask for help

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wCASE/)

Comment: @FXquincy apply CSS and images according to need, here is just logic

Answer (score 0):

You need to add doctype for css to work. Add this before the **head** tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you didn't set the initial size. you can use either css or javascript for that.

Recommended way is to use CSS. Add this to your style

```
#OurText {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

**See Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/RV5LE/**

I have cleaned your code a bit. and next time post your question with a copy on jsfiddle

Answer (score -1):

```
css('fontSize', fontSizes[0]+ 'px');
```

Should be:

```
css('font-size', fontSizes[0]+ 'px');
         ↑
```

That fontSize is used in animate().
Also you do not need that + 'px' all numeric css values can be given as numeric.

Comment: How this answer came out of nowhere, does it relate anything with this question????